# MKMapView overlay Vector tiles

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkoverlay, vector-tiles

Is there any way I can make vector tiles and overly them on `MKMapView` in iOS 6 and above?
I know how to overlay images using `MKOverlayView`, but they are raster images.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can render vector tiles in `MKTileOverlayRenderer`.

Here’s an example for a [GeoJSON tile renderer](https://github.com/halvards/GeoJSONTileOverlay) (can’t vouch for it though).